# C# set pictureboxes to hide using SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, picturebox

```
SqlDataReader reader = null;
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::vaja15.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);

cn.Open();

SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Uporabnik WHERE attacktype='melee' ", cn);

reader = sda.ExecuteReader();

reader.Read();

cn.Close();
```

My database has a column `attacktype` values melee or ranged. And a column `picturebox` with possible values pictureBox1, pictureBox2....

I didn't saved the pictures inside the database I just wrote their names like it was on the form. Now I'm trying to select those which are attacktype melee and set those which are ranged to `pictureBox1.Hide();` so I can filter the these 2 kinds. Can I do that with SQL code?

Comment: What's your table structure? Also you are getting some records from DB but not doing anything with them. You should itinerate inside reader results to hide your picturebox...

Comment: It's sounds like you have a _column_ named attacktype.  I would recommend pulling in your entire dataset and creating concrete objects.  Then you can hide your picturebox on your form based on the value of a field in the object.  Keep your UI separate from your database code and be all MVC-like.

Comment: My previous code was this one: richTextBox1.Text = reader[4].ToString(); but they overwrote each odher and i wasnt hiding any of the pictures

Comment: idk how to do that im sry